# Filter data from Umbraco backoffice listview

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I've a page called `Page` where I'll add some blocks called a `PageBlock`. This two are both document types. Under the `Page` you could create `Pageblock`s and `Page`s. Inside my listview on the backoffice, I'll only show the `Page`s. In the content three, I'll only show the `Pages`.

[image]

How could I do that?

I've tried to find a filter but nothing found and I wouldn't write a plugin. I'm using Umbraco 7.6

**Update:** I know how to create an listview but how could I make a filter to show only the childeren of one document type?

Comment: And how would you show the items with the doc type not on your filter?

Comment: Got exact the same question. It seems not possible. I wanted to created multiple list views, each showing their own document type

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand the question correctly, but I think what you want to do is set the permission of `Pages` to allow `Pageblocks` as its children (On the permissions tab of Pages)

Now if you want to display the children of `Pages` as a listview go to `List view` (top right) of `Pages` and enable `Yes - Enable list view`

If you want to both be able to view children in the tree and in a listview, you can leave the above option unchecked and add a `List View` property to the `Pages` documenttype (as displayed in your screenshot)

Comment: And how can I filter on the list view? I'll show only childeren of one document type. **P.S.:** this was my question. Sorry that I was unclear.